# Express $4\ln(x)+2\ln(x^4y^3)+5\ln(z)$ as a single logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem is to express $4\ln(x)+2\ln(x^4y^3)+5\ln(z)$ as a single logarithm.

Our teacher has shown us examples for the same base and when it's both add and subtract. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your title?  Does the final result need to be in log base-3?

Comment: I *think* Blake just wants to: "express the sum of three logarithms as a single logarithm," but the title is a little unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I was only wanting to express this as a single logarithm. :)

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $r\ln x=\ln(x^r)$, so $4\ln(x)=\ln(x^4)$. Also, $\ln(x)+\ln(y)+\ln(z)=\ln(xyz)$.

Comment: Good answer (+1), but it's unclear from the OP whether he needs his final answer in $\log_3$.

Comment: @KajHansen Hmm, yeah, that's true. I read the title and interpreted it as log base $3$. If not, then the last sentence is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, I do not need my answer in log3. I've gotten to ln(x^4)+ln(x^4y^3)^2+ln(z)^5.

Comment: @Blake So I'll edit my answer. Please read it again in five seconds.

Comment: I'm not 100% confident in this answer, but I got 
ln(x^16y^3z^5)^10. The ^10 at the end is making me unsure of the process I'm using.

Comment: @Blake You should have the following: $$\ln(x^4)+\ln(x^8y^6)+\ln(z^5)=\ln(x^{12}y^6z^5)$$

Comment: Oh my gosh! I see what I was doing wrong now. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

$\log(x) + \log(y) = \log(xy)$ and $n\log(x) = log(x^n)$ for logarithms of any base.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the identity $r \ln x = \ln (x^r)$?

I don't believe you need to change the base of any logarithms here, by the way.

Comment: Oops, I think I might've misinterpreted his question.  I thought the final result had to be in $\log_3$ due to the title.

Answer (score -1):

$4\ln(x)+2\ln(x^4y^3)+5\ln(z)$

By using identity, $a\times ln x=ln x^a$

$\implies \ln(x)^4+\ln{(x^4y^3)}^2+\ln(z)^5$

By using identity, $\ln x+ \ln y=\ln {xy}$

$\implies \ln(x)^{4+8}y^{3\times2}(z)^5$

Final Answer,

$\implies \ln(x)^{12}y^{6}(z)^5$